# GUI Winform and ending /killing process

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, process, exit

I have a c# GUI app and it's running a bunch of command line process one after another. How do I end/kill the app while the command line process is running?
I have an Exit button (button 3)  but it's not working if the process called is still running.

```
private void Run_Process(string process_to_run, string p_arg)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\nRunning " + process_to_run);

        try
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = process_to_run;
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = p_arg;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
            myProcess.WaitForExit();
            richTextBox1.AppendText("...Success");
            time_date = get_time();
            log_file.Write(time_date);
            log_file.WriteLine(process_to_run + "...Success");

        }

        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("\n" + ep.Message);
            time_date = get_time();
            log_file.Write(time_date);
            log_file.WriteLine(process_to_run + "...Failed. ERROR: " + ep.Message);
        }
    }     

  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db.connection.Close();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: Kill the app you are running this code from or kill the command prompt that is running the command?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're waiting for the process to exit:

```
myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

If this is happening in the UI thread, then you won't be able to exit (cleanly) until the method finishes, which means you have to wait for the process to finish.

If, instead, you don't wait on the process, you'll be able to exit immediately.

You should be able to rework your logic to not block by setting [Process.EnableRaisingEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) and then subscribing to the [Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event on the process.  You can add your text to your `RichTextBox` in this event, instead of blocking the main thread.

Comment: I need to keep the WaitForExit(). The problem is I have 8 process call one after another. I would prefer the process to be  killed right away and the next process wont be executed. can you give example?

Comment: @JohnRyann In that case, you could do this in a background thread, and kill the current process.  If you call WiatForExit on the UI thread, you'll block, and get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a call to `myProcess.WaitForExit();` in `Run_Process`.  If `Run_Process` gets called from the main thread, you're going to block that thread until the command line tool finishes.  That means `button3_Click()` can't fire until after `myProcess` has completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to exit, and exit now, try [Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx).

**Environment.Exit Method**

Terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code.

Comment: He's not going to get button clicks anyway because his UI thread is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Environment.Exit(1); really works.